# How to run the technical department of a non-technical start-up?

Tags: startup, development-environment

I have recently completed my bachelor's degree in Computer Engineer. I have had one small internship till now. 
I have little coding experience. 
After searching for months (Does not mean I am desperate for the job-Just wanted to clarify so that your answer is not based on it), I have been offered a job at a start-up to design and develop their web application for user interaction and management. I am the sole technical hire and will be the only person responsible for the development of the platform. The founders, though highly educated, do not have any sort of technical background.
It seems like an interesting opportunity but I am wondering if it too much responsibility too early?

I know this is not a standard programming question but I think this is a programming ability understanding type of question.

I would highly value your insight on this subject.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at your LinkedIn profile. Looks like you have great entry-level programmer qualifications.

Being the sole technical member of the team, with limited industry experience **may be a great opportunity for growth**.

However, the flip side argument is that you may be losing out on opportunities to grow with adequate mentorship. In all reality, the college/university CS/CE curriculum does not typically prepare you to handle real-world problems that senior-level software engineers address daily. **In a company where you are NOT the sole technical staff member, you will have the opportunity to collaborate with and learn from experienced pros. In my opinion, that is a huge factor in selecting your first job.**

So ... assuming this startup grows quickly ... are you qualified to:

- Make day-to-day technical decisions regarding scaling, security, and prioritization of product features?
- Interview, hire and evaluate the performance of additional technical personnel?
- Develop the full-stack of a web application including setting up and administering server, database, APIs and associated frameworks, client side technologies?

If you are uncomfortable with any of the above (which is a very limited set of questions) you probably aren't yet ready. It takes a long time before any of us are. Before I took my first leadership position in a startup, I had over 10 years of experience in multiple industries and with several technologies. But that's me ... you have to make this decision for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am pretty confident about taking technical decisions and hiring etc. 
However, I am not 100% confident about development. I was wondering if that kind of confidence and skill is possible to build on the job or not?

Comment: I'm curious about how you perceive the difference between making technical decisions like the ones I noted vs development. They must be considered together. But I guess more to your point, considering you a good junior developer candidate, I would anticipate that your product might work ... but it will very likely have some design flaws that will be attributed to lack of experience. If your bosses can accept that, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of the company. If there's going to be interaction between the users and the site a lot and it just doesn't serve the purpose of providing information, then you'll have to handle things on the server side as well to provide proper response and you need to be quite good with your stack and as a fresher, it isn't quite recommended to be a sole performer in the technical section of an entire firm.

Since you tell, web application, I assume the user does have to interact. I wouldn't go for it if I were you. But you haven't told about the level of expertise you possess in your skill set. So, can't say whether or not you'll be able to handle it.

and this is just my opinion btw.